# No window is created. Terminating application run. KIvy

Tags: python, kivy

No window is created. Terminating application run.
I have no idea how to fix it?
Can anyone help me to fix it?
I have no real documentation for that kivy problems
I don't understand how to run the class properly to display the windows

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import sqlite3 as sql


class CreateAccount(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        entreprise = ObjectProperty(None)
        email = ObjectProperty(None)
        password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        self.entreprise=entreprise
        self.password=password
        self.email=email

    def add_user(self):
         con=sql.connect("user.db")
         cur=con.cursor()
         cur.execute (""" INSERT INTO id (user,password, email) VALUES (?,?)""",(self.entreprise.text,self.password.text, self.email.text))
         con.commit()
         con.close()

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyMainApp(App):
    #  try:
    
    #      con=sql.connect("user.db")
    #      cur=con.cursor()
    #      cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE id(
    #          user text,
    #          password text, email text)
    #          """)
    #      con.commit()
    #      con.close()
    #  except:
    #      pass
        def build(self):
            return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: Is there any error output? Please share if any

Comment: What is in `my.kv`?

Comment: The CSS equivalent